# Upsert with modifications to excluded rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, merge

I have two tables:

**Table 1**:

```
ID ColA ColB Status
```

**Table 2**:

```
ColA ColB
```

I am trying to `MERGE` records from **Table 2** into **Table 1** in a way that:

1. For every row in **Table 2** present in **Table 1**, I set `Status = 1`
2. For every row in **Table 2** NOT present in Table 1, I insert the row into **Table 1** and set `Status = 1`
3. For every row in **Table 1** NOT present in **Table 2**, set `Status = 0`

Is it possible to do this in one statement? Currently, I am able to achieve `1` and `2` but am not sure how to get the third one as well:

```
MERGE INTO dbo.Table1 WITH(HOLDLOCK) AS Target
USING dbo.Table2 AS Source
ON Target.ColA = Source.ColA AND Target.ColB = Source.ColB
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET Target.Status = 1
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (ColA, ColB, Status) VALUES(Source.ColA, Source.ColB, 1);
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve `3` in the same statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the "NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE" clause.

```
MERGE INTO dbo.Table1 WITH(HOLDLOCK) AS Target
USING dbo.Table2 AS Source
ON Target.ColA = Source.ColA AND Target.ColB = Source.ColB
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET Status = 1
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (ColA, ColB, Status) VALUES(Source.ColA, Source.ColB, 1)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
    UPDATE SET Status = 0
;
```

Comment: For a moment, I thought the `SOURCE` in `NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE` is the `Source` alias! Just in case, anyone else faces that - `NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE` is a built-in expression.